# Can't print jupyter notebook properly

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am working on my office computer, which due to security restriction do not allow me to install program (like miktex, ....). So i decided to export my notebook to .html.

As you can see the rendering is not good:

- Some code is cutted
- A lot of space is spoiled, there is large blank margin that i would like to see disapear completely, and i do not need the "IN[1]" in front of cell to allow the code to be more visible

How would you do to get an html whose printing display is good ?
[image]

Comment: Note on the line length: According to PEP8, you should not have lines longer than 79 chars anyways. If you followed that rule, you would not have problems with wrapping the lines.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if following steps meet your requirements.

(Open the terminal in the corresponding path and then execute the command)

Following command exports the .ipynb file to .html file, and by specifying args(`TemplateExporter.exclude_input_prompt` and `TemplateExporter.exclude_out_prompt`), the `in[]` and `out[]` is ommitted.

```
jupyter nbconvert --to html --TemplateExporter.exclude_input_prompt=True --TemplateExporter.exclude_output_prompt=True <your_file>.ipynb
```

TemplateExporter.exclude_input_prompt=True removes the `in[]` while TemplateExporter.exclude_output_prompt=True removes the `out[]` from the generated .html file.